# Unable to download the source code of linux that I am running

Tags: 12.04, drivers, kernel, source-code

On my machine:

```
root@zaidi:/home/uzair# uname -r 
3.13.0-35-generic
```

Also:

> root@zaidi:/usr/src# ls
>
> linux-headers-3.11.0-15
>   linux-headers-3.11.0-23-generic linux-headers-3.11.0-15-generic 
>   linux-headers-3.11.0-24 linux-headers-3.11.0-20
>   linux-headers-3.11.0-24-generic linux-headers-3.11.0-20-generic 
>   linux-headers-3.11.0-26 linux-headers-3.11.0-22
>   linux-headers-3.11.0-26-generic linux-headers-3.11.0-22-generic 
>   linux-headers-3.13.0-35 linux-headers-3.11.0-23
>   linux-headers-3.13.0-35-generic

I am trying to download the linux source code for developing a driver:

```
root@zaidi:/home/uzair# apt-get install linux-source-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-source-3.13.0-35-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-source-3.13.0-35-generic'
```

How to get rid of this error ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to download the source of your Ubuntu kernel you need `apt-get source` not `apt-get install`. 
So  execute following commnad to fetch source of your linux kernel.

`sudo apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)`

Answer (score 0):

The source package of the Linux kernels in Ubuntu are called `linux`:

```
$ apt-cache show linux-image-$(uname -r)  | grep Source
Source: linux
$ apt-get source linux
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
NOTICE: 'linux' packaging is maintained in the 'Git' version control system at:
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git-repos/ubuntu/ubuntu-trusty.git
Need to get 124 MB of source archives.
```

You can also do:

```
apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: For me why `sudo apt-get source linux` is downloading only `linux-meta` pacakge of 18.5 KB

Answer (score 0):

First check the name of the source package of your linux through this command

> $ apt-cache show linux-image-$(uname -r)  | grep Source

then after knowing the source package of your linux, use apt-get command to get the source of your desired linux :)